# cron job not doing as expect... not working properly?

Tags: php, cron

I have a cron job setup to run every minute.

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/domain/public_html/ajax/cron.php > /home/domain/public_html/ajax/cron_output.log
```

Inside the cron.php, I have

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo 'cron ran';
?>
```

The cron_output.log I can see the modified date is updating each minute, but the contents off it is blank.  Why wouldn't it have "cron ran"?

This is a starting point for me, because I have a lot more code I'm trying to run, and it's not running.  I'm also writing to an error_log, but it's not writing to that log either.  However, the update date is changing on cron_output.log....

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: It's actually outputting two return carriage's (the rectangle characters)

Comment: If you have specified that the file should be executed as php in your crontab do you need `#!/usr/bin/php` in your php file?

Comment: Do get any error/warning message if you redirect both STDOUT _and_ STDERR (i.e. `&>` instead of `>`)?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved... there were some errors going on.